# CSS: align image icon of any size in the middle-center of a box

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I've been through several posts and visited other websites but still can't find a solution for this.
I tried several suggestions to no avail and I've been trying for several hours since yesterday and today to figure a solution.
So please, forgive me if this question may look duplicate but the truth is that none of the solutions worked out for me.
In fact, before rebuilding the whole page, I would appreciate some help from someone here.
My boss "simply" wants to see the icon to fit in the middle-center of the box. 
Since there's no text inside the box, the vertical-align: middle; does not apply. The images can be from different sizes, so I cannot count on a fixed size to position it.

Thanks

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.imageHolder {
    margin: 2px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: white;  
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#contenido .logo-radio .imageHolder {
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;  
}

<div class="logo-radio">
    <article class="imageHolder">
        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Logo AM 750"></a>
    </article>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZdLt/1)

Comment: well, if you have specific dimensions for the container, and you know the dimensions of your image, why not simply calculate the 2 and then add respective padding / margin?

Comment: That's what I explained when I wrote: "The images can be from diferent sizes, so I cannot count on a fixed size to position it."

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. Here's the code:

```
.imageHolder {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 72px;
    width: 72px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.imageHolder img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ZdLt/6/) to show it:

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this done in one of two ways:

1. Make it a background image:

   ```
   a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(yourimage.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. Position it absolutely:

   ```
   .imageHolder {
    margin: 2px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: white;  
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
   }
   #contenido .logo-radio .imageHolder {
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
   }
   #contenido .logo-radio .imageHolder a{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
   }
   img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you tried positioning the img absolutely with top:50% and then applying transform:translateY(-50%) ?

Answer (score -1):

`<div class="logo-radio" align="center">`

Comment: `align` is deprecated, see [http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2)